# angular dependency use fesm2015 instead of fesm2020

Tags: angular, typescript

in my Angular 13 project I have a npm dependency which has `fesm2020` and `fesm2015` module: see `package.json`

```
  "module": "fesm2015/ds-components.mjs",
  "es2020": "fesm2020/ds-components.mjs",
  "esm2020": "esm2020/ds-components.mjs",
  "fesm2020": "fesm2020/ds-components.mjs",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/ds-components.mjs",
```

when i serve the angular project, the `fesm2020` module is used. After lots of debugging I found out that the `fesm2020` module has strange behaviour but the `fesm2015` module would work. How can I tell angular to use the `fesm2015` module instead?

Comment: I love how no one has answered this!

Comment: I am facing reverse of this. need to access fesm2020 but its pointing to 2015. I am getting 3 import { UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms'; error owing to that.

Comment: startet a bounty, hopefully we find someone who knows

Comment: what target is in your tsconfig with this behaviour? And are you using angular_devkit as a builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all with Angular **before** 14 you could control [partly down-levelling with tsconfig.json](https://github.com/alan-agius4/angular-cli/blob/13.3.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.ts#L113-L126) Starting with Angular 14 it [will be controlled by browserlist](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/23185)
So for your Angular 13 application, the best way to do it is to use a [custom webpack config](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/13.x.x/packages/custom-webpack).
Because Angular team do not allow override webpack configuration, you might want to use this one (it will be applied over the angulars)

extra-webpack.config.ts

```
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';

export default {
  resolve: {
    conditionNames: ['es2020', 'es2015', '...'],
    // conditionNames: ['es2015', '...'],
  },
} as Configuration;
```

You can check the [demo I've created](https://github.com/Lonli-Lokli/ng-fesm2015-fesm2020-)

1. clone & run npm I
2. run npm run start
3. open browser console - FESM2020 will be displayed
4. stop build, **delete .angular folder** in the root with cached files
5. modify extra-webpack.config.ts to allow only es2015
6. repeat steps 2-3, you will see FESM2015

Answer (score 1):

check the tsconfig file, which helps developer to set "target" for es2015 or es2020. Please check the link below

> https://angular.io/guide/angular-package-format#flattening-of-es-modules